# Monotouch: PopToViewController and then pushing one causes views clashing on iPod/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I need to pop 3 controllers at once so I use `PopToViewController` method from Navigation controller and then I push a new one into it. It results in a views overlapping.
Both controllers, to what it had been popped and what is being pushed are `DialogViewControllers`. Besides this happens only on iPod/iPhone, on iPad it works correctly.

The code is just simple as:

```
NavigationController.PopToViewController(NavigationController.ViewControllers[NavigationController.ViewControllers.Count() - 1 - numberOfViews], animated);
NavigationController.PushViewController(viewController);
```

Any help?

Comment: Could you share some code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by setting animated parameter to false for iPhone.

```
NavigationController.PopToViewController(NavigationController.ViewControllers[NavigationController.ViewControllers.Count() - 1 - numberOfViews], false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of poping and pushing at the same time you should probably just replace the stack

```
UIViewControllers[] newStack = new UIViewController[NavigationController.ViewControllers.Count()-numberOfViews+1];
for (int i = 0; i < NavigationController.ViewControllers.Count()-numberOfViews; i++)
{
    newStack[i] = NavigationController.ViewControllers[i];
}
newStack[NavigationController.ViewControllers.Count()-numberOfViews] = viewController;
NavigationController.SetViewControllers(newStack, true);
```